# A technical question concerning convolution product.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory, functions, convolution

Let $v\in L^p(\Bbb R^d)$, $1\leq p<\infty$ be nonzero function, i.e., $v\not\equiv 0$.
Define $$u(x)= |v|*\phi(x)= \int_{\Bbb R^d} |v(y)|\phi(x-y)d y$$ with $\phi(x)= ce^{-|x|^2}$ and $c>0$ so that $\|\phi\|_{L^1(\Bbb R^d)}=1.$

Clearly we have $u\in L^p(\Bbb R^d)\cap L^\infty(\Bbb R^d)\cap C^\infty(\Bbb R^d)$, $u(x)>0$ for all $x\in \Bbb R^d$ and $u(x)\to 0$ as $|x|\to\infty$.

Question:

1- Is it possible that $u$ is nowhere locally constant, that is,
**the following does not hold:**

$$\exists a\in \Bbb R^d, r>0 \quad \text{such that $u(x)= u(a)$ for all $x\in B(a,r)$?}$$

2- If not, can we find $n\geq1$ such that $u_n$ fullfils the first question?
Here we put $u_1= u$ and $u_n=u_{n-1}*\phi$.

Comment: Why would $u$ be locally constant? Taking $v = \chi_{[0,1]}$, we get $u = \text{erf}(x+1)-\text{erf}(x)$, which is not locally constant.

Comment: $u$ is analytic so it is constant on some ball iff it is constant everywhere iff $v=0$

Comment: @reuns interesting argument. How do you show that $u$ is analytic?

Comment: $ u e^{|x|^2} =c \int_{\Bbb{R}^d} |v(y)| e^{-|y|^2} e^{\sum_{j=1}^d 2x_jy_j}dy$ that you can expand in power series in the $x_j$ and exchange $\int, \sum\ldots \sum$ because $ \int_{\Bbb{R}^d} |v(y)| e^{-|y|^2} e^{\sum_{j=1}^d2 |x_jy_j|}dy$  converges